# How to add table header column values and table cells values dynamically

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table which contains one fixed header by the name of `header`. Now at a time I have to add 10 values under the header into the cells of the table.It means number of rows will be 10 for this time, my concern is how to add column cells for the rows except header and  this should be done dynamically. Because the number of values in table header column can be changing as per the requirement.

Here is the fiddle..

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X6TZt/1/)

Please help me ..

Comment: Do you mean you want headers for each column?

Comment: @JoakimM yes and this should be dynamically

Comment: @JoakimM I want to add values under header column not to add column into the table

Answer (score 1):

I updated you fiddle.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/X6TZt/7/)

```
  $(function () {
    $("button").click(function (e) {
        var cols = $(this).val();

        // You'll want to do something here to get the column data
        var dataRow;
        var dataCol;
        for (i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
            dataCol = $("<th>Col " + i + "</th>");
            $("#table table thead").append(dataCol);
            dataRow = $("<tr></tr>");
            for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                dataRow.append($("<td>Row " + j + "</td>"));

            }
            $("#table table tbody").append(dataRow);
        }

        $("table").show();
        $("#clear").show();
        //$("#table table tbody").html("").append(data);
    });

    $("#clear").click(function () {
       $("table").hide();
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: I want to add values under table header as new row

Comment: Updated it completely!

Comment: Thank You Sir for answer but where is dynamic column and cells i need that one also...The solution that you provided needs to be integrated with my old one

Comment: Sigh. So you want both new rows with values AND new columns with headers?

Comment: How to achieve this sir?

Comment: If you want 3 columns, does this mean you want 3 rows as well?

Comment: This is not mandatory ,sometimes there will be 3 sometimes it can decrease or increase also

Comment: Yes. But let's say you push the button 3. Do you want 3 columns and 3 rows added?

Comment: For column ,YES but this is not mandatory for rows ,rows can be increasing or decreasing as per the records,if records no. of rows in records are 3 then 3 ,if its 6 it should be 6 ,but columns should be strictly as per the button push..

Comment: Is there any idea or suggestion to accomplish that?

Comment: Last try. Updated the fiddle. Removed your "header", but the principle is the same!

Answer (score 0):

Check the below jsfiddle. is it the way you want?

```
$(function () {
$("button").click(function (e) {
    var cols = $(this).val();
    // You'll want to do something here to get the column data
    var data = $("<tr></tr>").append();
   for (i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        $("#table table thead tr").after("<th>Column " + i +"</th>");
    data.append("<td>Col " +i+ "</td>");    
    }
    $("table").show();
    $("#clear").show();
    $("#table table tbody").html("").append(data);

});

$("#clear").click(function () {
   $("table").hide();
    $('table th:not(:first-child)').remove();
    $(this).hide();
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X6TZt/6/